# Bash script callable from web page

Tags: javascript, html, bash

I have a bash script that I want to give access to via a web server. The script does some basic text manipulation based on user input. I'd like to have the script accessible via a web page so the user can input the text to be manipulated and then copy-paste the result for use elsewhere.

Are there any recommended approaches and/or libraries for this? I don't know where to start. I'd like to minimise the need to learn any Perl or Python or PHP, an approach using vanilla HTML and Javascript as far as possible would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PHP Solution**

you can use php [shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) to run bash script and get the output as a string.

sample code as follows,

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('sh ./path/to/your_file.sh');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

But make sure that your script has right permissions to execute from web server user.

For an example apache2, default user is `www-data` should have permission to execute your script.

**Python Solution**

If you like to use python, then use [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) as below,

```
subprocess.call(["./path/to/your_file.sh"])
```

Comment: If there is a shebang in the script, I think that it's not necessary to invoke sh (and it would be better to use the default shell of your OS).